# How to generate a printout from .CSV in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I am looking for a way to upload a .CSV File and generate a Print out from the contense

It is generating password sheets for user of a website i have created.

I want it to do something like this

Name: Joe blogs

Username: j.blogs

E-Mail: Emailaddress@noware.com

Password: thepassword

so the "Name, Username, E-Mail, and password" are the headers in the csv and the others are the data

Any help would be appresiated

Comment: Start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Answer (score 0):

I like str_getcsv better..

```
$lines= file("file_name.csv");
$headers=array_shift($lines);
$header=str_getcsv($headers,',','"');
foreach ($lines as $l){
    $fields=str_getcsv($l,',','"');
    foreach ($fields as $i=>$f){
        echo $header[$i] . ": ". $f;
    }
}
```

That should be a start.

Comment: If one or more fields in the CSV have newline character: `abc,def,"ghi\njkl"\r\n`, `file()` and `fgets()` will read `abc,def,"ghi\n` as first line and `str_getcsv()` will get undesired result...

Comment: Thanks, havent had a chance to try it yet, but it looks like a start to what i want. Thanks again.